# Is there a way to share variables between 2 Cest tests?

Tags: php, automated-tests, codeception

I need to share variables between two tests. Is there any possible way?

It is Codeception on PHP.

I could make some XML document, store it, and then load it in other tests. But it is not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

After 4 months I found a solution. This type of testing is bad. 
This creates a dependency on previous tests.
It is better to use step / page objects + inheritance and codeception dataproviders.
1 file = 1 test

Comment: could you provide an example of using step / page objects + inheritance and codeception dataproviders?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved creating a BaseCest class with some properties that will be shared on classes that extends it. Looks like:

```
class BaseCest
{

    protected $token;

    public function _before(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $this->token = $GLOBALS['token'] ?? null;
    }
}
```

And on your AuthCest:

```
class AuthCest extends BaseCest
{

    public function loginSuccess(ApiTester $I)
    {
        global $token;
        # your tests go here
        $token = $I->grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath('$meta.token')[0];
    }
```

For future tests just call `$this->token`
Ps: Remember to use [@depends](https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Dependencies) to organize tests order